# Mantis or RedMine

Tags: bug-report

For our small business and team, I am researching a decent bugtracking system. I have narrowed it down to two that seem to fit our needs (easy to set up, easy to post bugs for non-programmers, SVN integration): Mantis and Redmine.

Mantis kind of has my vote because it is PHP/MySQL and I know that best, see installing and administering will be easier. However, if I search "Mantis or RedMine" in Google, I only find people who are migrating to RedMine.

What are your experiences with Mantis / RedMine?
Is it worth the effort of trying to get RedMine to work (add repositories, install Ruby, etc) on our production server?
How easy does the SVN integration compare (I found posts on the internet saying the RedMine integration "just works" and I have to setup/program the Mantis integration)?

Comment: This question won't be able to have a definitive answer and answers will be opinion based. Unfortunately they are not a good fit for this site. Can I suggest you ask another question that can be answered. Like "What are some of the issues that are causing people to migrate away from Manis?"

Answer (score 0):

Redmine is fantastic. Easy to use, with a very nice SVN viewer. There are a lot of nice plugins for it too. It doesn't need a programmer to setup or maintain.

Comment: I tried to install RedMine but ran into quite some troubles concerning Ruby. Our CentOS 5.7 servers do not seem to be all too happy with it.

Comment: The best way to install Ruby is [RVM](https://rvm.io/). It will automatically detect what libraries you need to install (and optionally install them for you).

Answer (score 0):

Redmine is very good. Mantis is bit more old fashioned. I suppose you have a look to Trac as it integrates Subversion, have its own wiki and is reasonable simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both, of the two I prefer Mantis.  My favorite of such solutions is [Zendesk](http://www.zendesk.com/).